Route path from one subdomain to another subdomain with a different path
I have a set of routes constrained to one subdomain that looks like the following:
www.domain.com/custom/:id
constraints(Constraints::Web) do
  resources :custom, only: [:show, :update], path: '/custom'
end

But I want to also accept the route in another subdomain, but on the root path:
custom.domain.com/:id
constraints(Constraints::Custom) do
  resources :custom, only: [:show, :update], path: '/'
end

The above does what I want, but this is a contrite example, there are a lot more resources in the constraints, and I want to avoid duplicating them.
Keeping things as DRY as possible, is there a cleaner way to accomplish this? Note that I also want to be able to support the helper. E.g. if I'm in www.domain.com/custom/:id I want the edit_custom_url(@thing) helper to point to www.domain.com/custom/:id/edit but if I'm in custom.domain.com/:id I want it to point to custom.domain.com/:id/edit
